# Not implementing a virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, virtual-functions

I wanted to ask, is there a problem with not implementing a virtual function? For example:

```
class Function { 
public: 
    virtual ~Function() {} 
    virtual double value(double x) const = 0; 
    virtual Function* clone() const = 0; 
protected: 
    virtual void print(ostream& os) const = 0; 
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Function& f); 
};
```

In a derived class of Function, if for example clone is not implemented, will it give a compilation error? Or will it be a runtime error if I try to call derived.clone()?

Comment: "Will it give a compilation error?"  Why don't you try it and find out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will get a compile error if you try to instantiate a class that has unimplemented pure virtual functions (including inherited ones).

Answer (score 1):

You'll get an error when compiling a code that creates an instance of that class or its derivates: `error C2259: cannot instantiate abstract class`.